# Can I disable Safari's smooth image scaling?

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I'd like to scale some pixel-art images up in-browser. Because they're pixel art it looks horrible if image smoothing happens.

In Firefox I can disable smoothing with "image-rendering:-moz-crisp-edges".

In IE there's "-ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor"... which is the default scaling mode anyway, mostly.

But I can't find a way to turn off smoothing in Safari for scaled images. Has anyone found a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's anything equivalent in Safari/WebKit.

See bottom of this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/image-rendering

Comment: Not really the answer I would have hoped for, but alas it seems accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old question, but I had the same doubt and got here when looking for an answer had the same doubt and I will post the solution for anyone in the same position.

What seems to do the trick in Safari is drawing to a canvas whose context has this flag: `ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;`

For all variations of this flag see:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled